# Semantic difference between <<use>> and <<invokes>> in UML diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, use-case

I really don't understand what is the difference between `<<use>>` and `<<invokes>>` in UML diagrams. I don't understand the difference because They seems equals when they use services from another class.

What is the semantic difference between `<<use>>` and `<<invokes>>` in UML diagram?

Answer (score 3):

UML 2.5 does not longer have an `<<invokes>>` stereotype. The difference in former UML versions is marginal and you can likely swap their meaning. That's probably the reason it has not been included in the new specs.

Answer (score 1):

According to the UML 2.5 specification (see 7.7.4 in the [spec](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/PDF/)), the `<<use>>` stereotype is used for a *Usage* dependency. The *Usage* dependency is a very general dependency where stereotypes `<<call>>`, `<<instanciate>>`, etc.  (see 22.1 in the [spec](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/PDF/)) are used for more specialized forms of the *Usage* dependencies.

In that sense I would consider the stereotype `<<invoke>>` as a specialized form of `<<use>>` where you explicitely want to point out that some sort of a method invocation is involved.